# Double output in command prompt and in txt

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Is there a way to have a Double output from a command in a Batch File? What we want to do is to get the output simultaneously in the command line and in a Text file.

we know that commands like this

```
ping 127.0.0.1 > block.txt
```

return the result in the Text file, but there is no way to show both as far as I know

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Upgrade to powershell?  `ping remote | tee filename | Out-Default`

Comment: What if I use a Talend and he generates .bat fies, does that work too?

Comment: Not sure about Talend.  But it seems likely that if it creates and runs a bath. 
 Then you almost certainly could have that bat run `powershell.exe` in your batch file with the -command or -file option pointed at a script..  You might check to see if it could run powershell though.

Comment: @Zoredache that was the solution we found! we did everything in PowerShell in the Task Scheduler with your command and invoked the BATCH file, everything works smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Zoredache stated, we used the Powershell command

```
.\power.bat | tee out.txt | Out-Default
```

Everything worked smoothly after that

Answer (score 2):

Kinda, but not really: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file

In short, for some commands, such as ping, you'd use this:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 > ping.txt & type ping.txt
```

And with others you'll do this:

```
dir > dir.txt | type dir.txt
```

And these will run the command and then output the content of the text file to the command window.

But what these will not do is show real-time output of the ping or dir command in the window.

Obviously, this is more of a problem if you were trying to run ping -t or similar where you're expecting a longer run time and probably wish to watch for something rather than just run something and read its brief output.

Powershell can show in the command window and output to a text file at the same time, so if powershell is an option you may be able to hack something together in there.